# How to query Amazon Best Sellers for a given category using Boto3. The Product Advertising API seems like overkill

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I want to query Amazon's top-selling products, and I came across boto3, a python sdk for AWS. I've done some googling around, and I can't find a straight answer, or documentation on how to query Amazon's Best sellers for a given category. Idk if it can even be done with boto3, but I can't find examples or anything. There is so much documentation on AWS, I find it difficult to sift through it all. I've seen reference for the Product Advertisement API, but it seems a bit overkill for a simple query, and rejects your application after a few months if you haven't people through links. Any guidance would be much-appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

boto3 is for manipulating resources on your AWS account, such as creating s3 buckets and objects, managing EC2 instances, etc. The AWS SDKs do not have support for the Amazon Product Advertising API. There are currently Java, Perl, C# and PHP libraries for this API, but no python. Regardless of the interface used, the API requires registration.

Comment: Thanks. Is the Advertising API the only way to query marketplace data?

Comment: As far as I know, yes